# RegExp error in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Binding a regexp to a parameter in perl, I'm getting the following error:
`syntax error at ./ctime.pl line 23, near "/^\((\d{2}):(\d{2})\)/)"
Execution of ./ctime.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Here is the line where I try to bind it:

`$_[0] =~ /^\((\d{2}):(\d{2})\)/)/;`

I'm trying to match an hours/minutes combination in parens, such as `(99:99` or `(01:24)`. There will always be four digits.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$_[0] =~ s/^\((\d{2}):(\d{2})\)/)/;`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$_[0] =~ /^\((\d{2}):(\d{2})\)/)/;
```

should be

```
$_[0] =~ /^\((\d{2}):(\d{2})\)/;
```

You accidentally duplicated two characters near the end of the line.

---

PS — As a note of caution, you'll have problems if you try to pass `$1` or the like as an argument to function that contains this code because you use `$_[0]` directly.

```
sub f {
   print("$_[0]\n");              # a
   print $_[0] =~ /a/ ?1:0,"\n";  # 1
   print("$_[0]\n");              # [empty string]
   print $_[0] =~ /a/ ?1:0,"\n";  # 0
}
'a'=~/(.)/;
f($1);
```

Comment: Damnit so frustrating. Thank you though, and I'll change the parameter passing to be safe.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend indexing `@_` directly but there isn't a problem with using the capture variables `$1` etc. as they are implicitly localized to the current block.

Comment: @Borodin, Code added to my node to prove the problem I mentioned exists.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `/)` just before the end. The offending line should be:

```
$_[0] =~ /^\((\d{2}):(\d{2})\)/;
```